# Automating Ruby on rails testing

Tags: automated-testing, ruby-on-rails

I'm the only software engineer in a 40 person organization, and we work with various contractors to write our RoR site. (I'm mostly a python programmer, so have limited experience in this space)

We are running up against the limits of manual testing. We have unit tests, but there are a lot of things that can't be tested easily that way. Other than that, we're basically having people manually test all use-cases, and that's just not sustainable. We have no explicit QA people.

What are the best practices/tools (Tools most importantly) for automating testing?

Comment: Your question probably will be closed for "Need Focus". There is no such thing as "automate the testing" since computers can't test (https://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/856). I would suggest understanding which risks do you want to have computer support in testing and then create questions regarding those types of risk.

Comment: I know that there are MANY tools for automating testing... unit tests, something called "cucumber", etc... that's the sort of thing I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you hire some dedicated people to write automation and focus on it providing quick feedback to developers (as opposed to separate verification test automation later in the process).

You will need teachers, guides, coaches and mananagement buy-in for new practices at the director level at least and probably C-Suite.

The main tool to use is your brain to figure out what mix of changes and people and tools are right for the specifics of your organization and how it works currently (more than the high level you provided).

I suggest using Agile Testing by Lisa Crispen and Janet Gregory as your guide.

Comment: We're a 40 person nonprofit with 1 software person. We can't hire dedicated testing people...  So, new practices are actually easy...

Comment: Change in thinking to understand new practices and think in different ways and stop old ways is typically hard. Procedures seem easy but mindsets harder. That said I would explore the selenium ide with a junior dev or intern based on the additional info